# make a new column for each row that meets a criteria R

Tags: r, purrr, categorical-data, dplyr

I have two datasets. The first one has someone's location and their distance in miles to different destinations. The second dataset has the list of all the destinations. I want R to make a column that pulls the name of each destination that is under 1000 miles away.

Here's a sample of the first dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
start_location <- tibble(location = c("Anhui China", "Amersfoort Utrecht Netherlands", "Akita Akita Japan"),
lon = c(117.92, 5.38, 140.1),
lat = c(30.60, 52.16, 39.71),
dist_beijing = c(658, 5686, 1250),
dist_shanghai = c(241, 5510, 1200),
dist_tokyo = c(1300, 5775, 280),
dist_prague = c(5173, 417, 5415), 
dist_pomezia = c(5555, 474, 5927),
dist_antwerp = c(5498, 77, 5612))
```

Here's the second dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
destinations <- tibble(destinations = c("beijing china", "shanghai china", "tokyo japan", "prague czech republic", "pomezia italy", "antwerp belgium"),
lon = c(116.4, 121.47, 139.65, 14.43, 12.50, 4.40),
lat = c(39.90, 31.23, 35.67, 50.07, 41.67, 51.22))
```

And here's what I want the dataset to look like:

```
library(tidyverse)
solution <- tibble(location = c("Anhui China", "Amersfoort Utrecht Netherlands", "Akita Akita Japan"),
lon = c(117.92, 5.38, 140.1),
lat = c(30.60, 52.16, 39.71),
nearest1 = c("shanghai china", "antwerp belgium", "tokyo japan"),
nearest2 = c("beijing china", "prague czech republic", NA),
nearest3 = c(NA, "pomezia italy", NA))
```

I know how to make it find the shortest distance, but I'm struggling on making it yield a column name for each one. Also, though this one had three nearest, I don't necessarily want to limit it to only 3. I just want it to make columns for each destination that is under 1000 miles.

I assume I should use case_when and pmap, but I can't figure out how to add the if statement and allow it to make multiple columns.

If it it can't make columns easily, I can also have it make one column that lists all the the destinations under 1000 miles in order (for instance, if "beijing china, shanghai china"), because then I could at least separate it out with tidyr.

Also, if possible, I'd like a tidy solution, if possible.

Thank you!!

Comment: ```t(apply(start_location[,-c(1,2,3)], 1, function(x) names(x)[order(x)]))``` as a starting point for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
result<-start_location %>% gather("destination","distance",-(1:3)) %>%
  filter(distance<=1000) %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  arrange(distance) %>% 
  mutate(id=paste0("nearest",row_number())) %>% 
  select(-5) 
result$destination<-gsub("dist_","",result$destination)
result$destination<-sapply(result$destination, function(x) grep(x,destinations$destinations,value=TRUE))
result<-result %>% spread(id, destination)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   location [3]
  location                     lon   lat nearest1       nearest2          nearest3   
  <chr>                      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>             <chr>      
1 Akita Akita Japan         140.    39.7 tokyo japan    NA                NA         
2 Amersfoort Utrecht Nethe~   5.38  52.2 antwerp belgi~ prague czech rep~ pomezia it~
3 Anhui China               118.    30.6 shanghai china beijing china     NA
```

The key is in arranging the destinations (which have been grouped by starting location) by distance, and then assigning an `id` tag according to their order -- then you can `spread` the destinations into columns based on these `id` tags.

I added a couple of steps before the `spread` to replace the names of destination columns with the actual names of the destinations from the `destinations` dataframe -- that may introduce some errors if you have a destination city that's also a country's name (e.g., Mexico City) and that country also appears in another destination, so just keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you! I would not have thought of doing this with group_by, filter, and gathering.

Comment: Long data is generally easier to work with in terms of filtering and arranging, I find, so it's the first thing I try to use when thinking of a solution.